# Inferring RAM ALTERA from vhdl of HDL CODER

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, matlab, simulink

I've generated vhdl from Simple port RAM and Dual port RAM in simulink and I tried to synthesize  with Quartus 14 and 16 on Arria V and 10. The option to allow RAM for any size is ON but I don't understand why it isn't recognized. Have you never seen this?

I also synthesized the Altera template with the same data and address and it's correctly recognized.
I used matlab 2016

Thank you to all

Answer (score 2):

The Quartus synthesizer has some serious issues.  It's extremely particular about inferring RAMs as well as performing certain constant elaboration (i.e. initializing a RAM with a trig function such as sine).  It's infuriating.  The most annoying thing is most of this stuff will be properly recognized by the Xilinx tools.  I recommend just rewriting it using the provided template instead of using simulink generated code.